# How to make login form not fit whole width of screen

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, responsive

I created a login form that currently is fitting the whole width of the screen. I tried to make the forms width smaller by using width:50% which sized the form perfectly but made the form stick to the left side of the screen. How would I change the forms sizing while still making it centered and responsive? Is there simply a attribute I'm unaware of?

```css
html,
body {
  height:100%;
  font-family: 'Alegreya Sans', sans-serif;
}

#header {
  background:linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)), url('../img/hero.jpeg') center center no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
  height:100%;
  color:white;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}

#header h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-size: 500%;
  font-weight: 300;
}

#header h3 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-size: 200%;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.login {
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  padding:30px;
  border-radius:10px;
}
```

```html
<section id="header">
  <div class="col-sm-12 login">
    <h1>Apple ID</h1>
    <h3>Manage your Apple account</h3>
    <form>
      <fieldset class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only">Apple ID</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Apple ID">
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
      </fieldset>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-info btn-block">login</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Bootstrap's Grid classes according to the width of screens.

Do this:

```
<div class="login col-xs-12 col-xs-offset-0 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
```

Instead of:

```
<div class="col-sm-12 login">
```

You might have a look at the [Bootstrap Grids](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid). Hope this helps!

Comment: This in combination with margin: 0 auto; did the trick! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try this

**[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xwL5f9gv/)**

**css**

```
html,
        body {
            height:100%;
            font-family: 'Alegreya Sans', sans-serif;
        }

        #header {
            background:linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)), url('../img/hero.jpeg') center center no-repeat;
            background-size:cover;
           /* height:100%;*/
            color:white;
            display:flex;
            align-items:center;
        }

        #header h1 {
            text-align: center;
            font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
            font-size: 500%;
            font-weight: 300;
        }

        #header h3 {
            text-align: center;
            font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
            font-size: 200%;
            font-weight: 100;
        }

        .login {
            background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
            padding:30px;
            border-radius:10px;
            margin:0 auto;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Going by the class names, it looks like you are using bootstrap as your framework.

`<div class="col-sm-12 login">` is setting the login form to the whole width of the screen (bootstrap works on a grid system of 12)

Change the div class to `<div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 login">` and this will create a login form that is 6 column wide (50% the width of the container), offset from the left by 3 columns (25% the width of the container). Adjust these values to suit.

Answer (score 0):

You using bootstrap's grid and you set `col` number to 12 here:
`<div class="col-sm-12 login">`, it makes the width of this div full width of the grid system. If you want it to be half width, you should set `class="col-sm-6"` to 6.

Answer (score 0):

centering your form using twitter bootstrap

```
<form class="center-block col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-12">
```